# Assistance with GROUP BY SOQL Query

Tags: soql, query, conga, conga-composer

I have created a Conga Composer SOQL query that takes a bundled product with recurring and non recurring items, sums them by charge type, and masks the child products with the bundle parent name and description for display purposes. Below is an example of how it works:

[image]

As you can see, the child part sell prices are totaled based on charge type, and the child SKUs are grouped by the bundle parent. The output works perfectly...HOWEVER

The issue is that if I were to add the same SKU twice (Bundle Parent 1), the output would summarize both. So using the output example above, if I had TWO bundle Parent 1 SKUs on my quotelines, the output would display the two lines but with a sell price of 300 for the Recurring and 800 for the One-time (because there are two of the same SKU).When in reality, I want the query to summarize each UNIQUE Bundle, even though the name may be the same. This is because the descriptions may be changed to show specific information. Below is my SOQL Query for the recurring items:

SELECT Configured_SKU__c, Configured_SKU_Description__c, MAX(SBQQ__Quantity__c), SUM(SBQQ__ListPrice__c), SUM(Unit_Sell_Price__c), SUM(Recurring__c) FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c = '{pv0}' AND Charge_Type__c = 'Recurring' AND Configured_SKU__c != '' GROUP BY Configured_SKU__c,Configured_SKU_Description__c ORDER BY Configured_SKU__c DESC

I am not sure how to adjust so that it groups by each UNIQUE bundle...

Comment: Have you looked at [GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm)? Would that help you solve your problem?

Comment: @sfdcfox Can I group by the salesforce group name? My thought is that I could do this aggregation as I am doing in the syntax above, but only apply it to products in a unique quoteline group. That way I could format the quote output so that SKUs with same name are split out instead of summarized. I tried doing this but received a malformed query error...